# How to place dropzone thumbnail outside dropzone preview template

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I know this is a stupid question
but anyone know how to place dropzone thumbnail outside dropzone previewTemplate

```
<div class="template">
   <div class="previews">
   </div>
</div>
<!-- this is previewTemplate area -->

<div class="image-profile">
  <img data-dz-thumbnail>
</div>
<!-- this is thumbnail preview area, outside from previewTemplate -->
```

Is it possible to do this?
or have a another possible way?

or maybe how to get dropzone thumbnail source, something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Upload complete try

```
//.each because there can be multiple thumbnails in case of multiple uploads
$('img[data-dz-thumbnail]').each(function(i, img){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    console.log(imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I think you're don't get it, what I mean

Comment: What I undrstood was that you need the src of the thumbnail to post it outside of the drop zone. The code I sent you, you can put it on upload complete trigger and once the Thumbnail is available it will give you the src attribute value in `imgSrc` variable.

Comment: No, I mean, dropzone preview thumbnail, I'm using dropzone with autoqueue is disabled, I'm using submit button, then before submit,
thumbnail is appear, the thumbnail is appear outside dropzone previewtemplate,

Comment: And when you submit the thumbnail appears in `div class="previews"` right?

Comment: Same problem, this is result from my console log function = [object File] data:image/png;base64,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

Comment: Just put this in the `src` attribute of the `<img />` outside the dropzone and see what happens